# Mysql subtract two days from date_format

Tags: mysql, date, compare

I would like to get all the records whose date is two days greater than the current date. I want to compare only the month and the day. 
This is what I have tried.

```
select * from reminder where date_sub(date_format(Birthday,%m-%d),interval 2 day)=Date_Format(curdate(),'%m-%d');
```

But it doesn't return any records.

For Example, It should return all records with dates like:

```
1977-07-04
1984-07-04
1989-07-04
1995-07-04
```

Comment: Move your where clause to the select `date_sub(date_format(Birthday,%m-%d),interval 2 day), Date_Format(curdate(),'%m-%d');` for a second and compare the results...see anything off?

Comment: I tried that. But, it doesn't seem to return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date_sub function expects a date. Instead you pass it a string that you get from date_format function. Maybe it tries to cast it back to date. But it should not have to.

Instead you should perform date arithmetic first, and convert to string later:

```
 where date_format(date_sub(Birthday,interval 2 day),'%m-%d') = Date_Format(curdate(),'%m-%d')
```